# Why do I get the "method has no supported translation to SQL" error?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

i get this error

```
{"Method 'System.DateTime ConvertTimeFromUtc(System.DateTime, System.TimeZoneInfo)' has no supported translation to SQL."}
```

when i try to execute this linq to sql

```
var query = from p in db.Posts
            let categories = GetCategoriesByPostId(p.PostId)
            let comments = GetCommentsByPostId(p.PostId)
            select new Subnus.MVC.Data.Model.Post
            {
                Categories = new LazyList<Category>(categories),
                Comments = new LazyList<Comment>(comments),
                PostId = p.PostId,
                Slug = p.Slug,
                Title = p.Title,
                CreatedBy = p.CreatedBy,
                CreatedOn = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(p.CreatedOn, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Romance Standard Time")),
                Body = p.Body
            };
return query;
```

is there another place i can convert the date to right format currently i have a macro i my _global.spark fil but that seems wrong

```
<macro name="DateAndTime" Date="DateTime">
# Date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Romance Standard Time"));
${Date.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy")} at ${Date.ToString("hh:mm")}
</macro>
<macro name="Date" Date="DateTime">
# Date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Romance Standard Time"));
${Date.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy")}
</macro>
```

**Update:** i now understand where the code does not work but when i remove it i get then same error for this code

```
 public IQueryable<Subnus.MVC.Data.Model.Comment> GetCommentsByPostId(int postId)
    {
        var query = from c in db.Comments
                    where c.PostId == postId
                    select new Subnus.MVC.Data.Model.Comment
                    {
                        Body = c.Body,
                        EMail = c.EMail,
                        Date = c.CreatedOn,
                        WebSite = c.Website,
                        Name = c.Name
                    };

        return query;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ-to-SQL only translates a subset of operations - and it trying (and failing) to write ConvertTimeFromUtc as TSQL. Some operations have TSQL counterparts (dateadd/datediff/etc) - but not all. You might choose to do your projection (select) using the raw value, and only do the ConvertTimeFromUtc once you have the object in memory (via LINQ-to-Objects).

For example - you could create the objects just using p.CreatedOn, then do the rest afterwards. Not ideal, but life. LINQ-to-Entities claims better translation options, but is significantly more complex. Depending on your scenario, LINQ-to-SQL also offers udf support, which *sometimes* lets you offload these things to the db - *if* there is a way of writing it as a udf - for example, you could write a method on the data-context and mark is as a composable function ([`[Function]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.functionattribute.aspx)), then something like:

```
 ...
    CreatedOn = ctx.MapDate(p.CreatedOn)
 ....
```

Which would then use the TSQL from `[Function]` - i.e. something like:

```
....
    dbo.MapDate(t2.CreatedOn)
....
```

Comment: can you add a link to how to use [Function] i linq to sql datacontext

Comment: At the simplest level, just drag the UDF onto the designer. To do manually, see here for a trivial example: http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/browse_thread/thread/636a151186564c60/f10d7ef0c325caf3

Answer (score 3):

Linq-to-Sql can't translate arbitrary .net functions into SQL.  Some DateTime functions can be translated however, and a full list is available here:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882657.aspx

In your example if you calculate the time offset outside of the projection you can add the offset to the retrieved "CreatedOn" DateTime using the AddMinutes method which has a supported translation into SQL.

Comment: to do that i need to know the time i pick out of the database because it is not always gmt+1 in the summer it is gmt+2

Comment: Um yeah, that's true(!).  I have a feeling there is a way around that, let me have a ponder...